# rm -rf until success

Tags: bash, rm

I have a deployment script that removes all files in a tmp folder before continuing, but sometimes during the deployment, a process will use one of the tmp files, making the `rm`command fail. This is how my script looks like

```
rm -rf app/tmp
tar -xf app.tar
```

That is an over-simplification of what is happening, please don't try to suggest improving the deployment process, this is strictly a question about the `rm` command

I am thinking of something like

```
# pseudo code
while [[ ! rm -rf app/tmp ]]; do sleep 1; done
tar -xf app.tar
```

In other words: continue to try to delete folder until nobody added files there, then continue the script.

Do you know of a syntax that would allow this in bash?

Currently the script fails and never extracts the tar files.

Thanks for your input here.

Comment: If you were to remove `test`(1) (aka `[`) from your "pseudo code", I believe it would work in bash (ie, `while ! rm -rf app/tmp; do sleep 1 ; done`).

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop isn't comparing anything.  It needs to match on something; in this case, we want to know if the directory exists.  If it exists, delete it with `rm`, otherwise if doesn't exist, exit the loop and run the `tar` command.  You don't want to use the `rm` command inside the `while` condition.

```
# pseudo code
while [[ -d app/tmp ]]; do rm -rf app/tmp; sleep 1; done
tar -xf app.tar
```

Comment: I was looking more forward to a solution checking the out status of rm, but this will do

Comment: sorry I removed this as accepted answer, but I thought that even though your answer solves the problem in question, a more general answer is found in another question from SO, I posted it below

Comment: If you use the -f option with `rm` with this code example, it will always work, because the "force" option does not prompt and ignores files that don't exist.  The `rm` command as written should always complete.

Comment: my problem was that during the command some other process adds a content into the tmp dir, this is the output of the command, thus making my complete cron fail:``rm -rf app/tmp/*
rm: cannot remove ‘app/tmp/dir1’: Directory not empty``

Answer (score 1):

Looks I found the answer in another question "How can you run a command in bash over until success"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5274386/2296642

I should use `until` syntax.

```
until rm -rf app/tmp; do echo trying again; done
tar -xf app.tar
```

Comment: also, it seems I could have accomplished the same thing as I wanted with `while` by skipping the `test`(`[`) command with `while ! rm -rf tmp/; do echo trying again; done`